# Why does the act of introducing a destructor result in worse codegen? (Passed by reference instead of by value in a register)

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, calling-convention, micro-optimization, abi

Take this simple example:

```
struct has_destruct_t {
    int a;
    ~has_destruct_t()  {}
};

struct no_destruct_t {
    int a;
};


int bar_no_destruct(no_destruct_t);
int foo_no_destruct(void) {
    no_destruct_t tmp{};
    bar_no_destruct(tmp);
    return 0;
}

int bar_has_destruct(has_destruct_t);
int foo_has_destruct(void) {
    has_destruct_t tmp{};
    bar_has_destruct(tmp);
    return 0;
}
```

`foo_has_destruct` gets slightly worse codegen, because the destructor seems to force `tmp` onto the stack:

```
foo_no_destruct():                   # @foo_no_destruct()
        pushq   %rax
        xorl    %edi, %edi
        callq   bar_no_destruct(no_destruct_t)@PLT
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        popq    %rcx
        retq
foo_has_destruct():                  # @foo_has_destruct()
        pushq   %rax
        movl    $0, 4(%rsp)
        leaq    4(%rsp), %rdi
        callq   bar_has_destruct(has_destruct_t)@PLT
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        popq    %rcx
        retq
```

https://godbolt.org/z/388K1EfYa

But why does this need to be the case given that the destructor is 1) trivially inlinable and 2) empty?

Is there any way to include a destructor at zero cost?

Comment: `~has_destruct_t()  = default;` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number that does work, but sometime you want a real destructor but there seems to be an inherent cost.

Comment: @Noah When you do `~has_destruct_t()  {}` your destructor is no longer trivial.  I suspect that is all the optimizer checks for and since your destructor is not trivial it doesn't apply the optimizations.  The only time you should need a real destructor is when you are managing some resource and you need to manually handle releasing that resource when the object is destroyed.  Otherwise the default should "do the right thing" as long as all members are RAII types.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Yes, even `{}` is considered "non-trivial" by the ABI.  If you tried to consider some function bodies trivial but others not, you'd be opening up a big can of worms like whether `{ int dummy=0; }` is still trivial, since it will optimize away to nothing... But you never want the calling convention to depend on how good the compiler is at optimizing, so you just draw the line somewhere that doesn't depend on what's inside the `{}`.  The most clear-cut place to draw the line is that even `{}` counts as non-trivial, so compilers don't need special handling to remember that source.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Your examples provide definitions (not just declarations) for `bar` so it can inline and optimize away, leaving `int foo() { return 0; }` which of course compiles efficiently.  https://godbolt.org/z/ce8hx3beo shows that if you leave it as just a prototype, GCC compiles it to the same asm inside an anonymous namespace.  Clang treats it as an error that you call a function that's not defined within that anonymous namespace, GCC just warns.  The "worse codegen" this question is asking about is a difference in calling convention, not a missed-optimization. (I edited the title.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, I seem to have missed the point slightly :-)

Comment: @Noah *Is there any way to include a destructor at zero cost?* -- By introducing a user-defined destructor, even if it's empty, you've changed the traits of the class.  By changing the traits of the class, you've opened yourself up for the optimizer to assume things that may be detrimental to performance, or possibly a non-optimal template specialization is selected if the type is used in templated code.  [See this](https://godbolt.org/z/nrhW1j1E9).  That's why it is now recommended to either not write a destructor if it's empty, or declare it as `= default`.

Comment: @NathanOliver: update to my previous comment: consider the case where the class signature only declares a destructor but doesn't *define* its body.  If you treat a `{}` body as still trivial, then the ABI depends on whether a caller can see a definition for the destructor or not, which is obviously terrible (e.g. LTO or not for cross-file inlining / definition visibility).  Or that pulling the definition out of the class signature always changes the ABI, whether a definition is visible or not, which also seems pretty terrible and weird, but at least could work.

Answer (score 9):

The Itanium C++ ABI calling convention defines that a type with non-trivial destructor must be passed on the stack and `~has_destruct_t()  {}` is always a non-trivial destructor. A trivial destructor must either be implicitly-declared or defaulted on its first declaration (`~has_destruct_t() = default`).

The rule is necessary to make copy elision work if a prvalue is passed as function argument. Copy elision requires that the address of the function parameter is the same as the address of the temporary object materialized from the the prvalue function argument and that's an observable property.

So the caller needs to provide memory for the temporary object (and at the same time the function parameter object) to assure equal addresses.

This copy elision is mandatory since C++17 for types with non-trivial (and non-deleted) destructor, but was also allowed in all previous C++ standard editions, which the Itanium C++ ABI made use of.

---

If you don't intent to do anything in the destructor body, then don't declare it at all, except if you need to also make it `virtual`, in which case `virtual ~has_destruct_t() = default;` will do.

Comment: @NathanOliver https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#class.temporary-3 is an additional permission to introduce temporary objects, effectively making the copy elision non-mandatory for these cases. That's the only reason that passing in a register is possible in OP's `no_destruct_t`. Technically it is true that, since C++17 and absent this special case, there is only one object and that the prvalue expression in the argument directly initializes the function parameter object, but that's not very intuitive to explaining what "copy elision" means in the context.